# Export C# List to Csv file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was trying to export my C# list to Csv file. All is set well. But the thing is field seperator is not working properly. its showing like, my string with " at the end (eg: 0000324df"). Here is my Controller code.

```
IEnumerable stockexpo = stockexp; // Assign value
        MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
        writer.Write("ItemNo,");
        writer.Write("Repeat Count");
        writer.WriteLine();
        foreach (StockResult order in stockexpo)
        {
            writer.Write(String.Format("{0:d}", order.ItemNumber));
            writer.Write("\"");
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.Write("\"");
            writer.Write(order.Count);
            writer.Write("\"");
            writer.Write(",");
            writer.WriteLine();
        }
        writer.Flush();
        output.Position = 0;

        return File(output, "text/comma-separated-values", "stockexp.csv");
```

I need to know how i can seperate the field values appropriately. Anyone can help me for this.

Comment: Does some of your data contain speachmarks? Looking at your code it is doing exactly what you have asked it to do...

Comment: No speachmarks in my data. but its (") showing with every value.

Comment: writer.Write("\""); <- What do you expect this line to do?

Comment: Its like this:0000000027"
0000000028"
0000000029"
0000000030"
0000000031"
0000000032"
0000000033"
0000000034"
0000000035"
0000000036"

Answer (score 3):

```
  writer.Write("\"");
```

This line of code will be outputting a " every time. Why have it at all?

Also, I wouldn't have a comma before the WriteLine, since there is no need to delimit the end of the file.

```
IEnumerable stockexpo = stockexp; // Assign value
    MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(output, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Write("ItemNo,");
    writer.Write("Repeat Count");
    writer.WriteLine();
    foreach (StockResult order in stockexpo)
    {
        writer.Write(order.ItemNumber);
        writer.Write(",");
        writer.Write(order.Count);
        writer.WriteLine();
    }
    writer.Flush();
    output.Position = 0;

    return File(output, "text/comma-separated-values", "stockexp.csv");
```

Comment: This time i am getting the last two chars in the string. like, the actual value => 0000000043. But i am getting only 43.

Comment: What is the type of order.ItemNumber?

Comment: Then why use String format like you were. See my edited answer.

Comment: In that case, your order.ItemNumber is not a string type.

Comment: Its a String and Unique Type.

Comment: its a string type. My class declaration is:public string ItemNumber { get; set; }
        public int Count { get; set; }

Comment: Put a breakpoint in, I don't believe that string ever contains the leading zeroes.

Comment: Its writing to the stream including Zeroes.

Comment: But in the file just skipping out zeroes and showing out the rest.