# asp.net mvc create csv file in memory without creating a physical file and send email as attachment

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filestream

I'm working on asp.net mvc web application development, where I need to create a CSV file in-memory and send as attachment of email.

I had a look at this stack overflow solution below:
[Export C# List to Csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983586/export-c-sharp-list-to-csv-file)

Unfortunately, this solution returns File Result and doesn't fit with my requirement.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: An example of mailing an attachment from a memory stream:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5336239/how-to-attach-a-file-from-memorystream-to-a-mailmessage-in-c-sharp Just try and put it together with the link that you posted in your question. SEt the mime type to text/csv. Hope this helps.