# Column list structure to CSV

Tags: c#, parsing, .net-core

I need to generate a report csv with this structure

```
public class ReportColumn
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<string> Childs { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

to this CSV structure

```
Header field 1; Header field 2; Header field 3
lorem ipsum; lorem ipsum; lorem ipsum;
lorem ipsum; lorem ipsum; lorem ipsum;
```

My difficult is to relate the correct line field with their column parent

```
public string DrawCsv(List<ReportColumn> reportColumns)
{
}
```

Comment: have you tried anyting? SO is n t a code writing service, try something, if you get stuck post the code you have so far and say what problem you are seeing. BTW there is a very good c# csv library called csvhelper

Comment: This is a repetitive question.
Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983586/export-c-sharp-list-to-csv-file

Comment: My issue was how to transforms a data column structure to a data row structure, My solution was change the data structure to data row. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems impossible =)

CSV is a row-oriented structure. You need to reorganize your data.

For example, create a model that corresponds to your row:

```
    public class ReportRow
    {
        [Description("Name 1")]
        public string Column1 { get; set; }

        [Description("Name 2")]
        public string Column2 { get; set; }

        [Description("Name 3")]
        public string Column3 { get; set; }
    }
```

In this case, the method that makes CSV string will be:

```
    public static string DrawCsv(List<ReportRow> rows, bool showHeader = false)
    {
        var result = string.Empty;

        if (showHeader)
        {
            var header = string.Empty;
            var r = rows.First();
            foreach (var prop in r.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                DescriptionAttribute attr = (DescriptionAttribute)prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), true)[0];
                header += attr.Description + "; ";
            }
            result += header.TrimEnd() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        foreach (var row in rows)
        {
            var line = string.Empty;
            foreach (var prop in row.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                line += prop.GetValue(row) + "; ";
            }
            result += line.TrimEnd() + Environment.NewLine;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

With `DescriptionAttribute` you are able to avoid creating a special field for column naming.
Now we can test this:

```
        var reportRows = new List<ReportRow>
        {
            new ReportRow { Column1 = "Lorem ipsum 1", Column2 = "dolor sit 1", Column3 = "amet 1" },
            new ReportRow { Column1 = "Lorem ipsum 2", Column2 = "dolor sit 2", Column3 = "amet 2" },
            new ReportRow { Column1 = "Lorem ipsum 3", Column2 = "dolor sit 3", Column3 = "amet 3" }
        };

        var str = DrawCsv(reportRows, true);
```

Result will be:

```
Name 1; Name 2; Name 3;
Lorem ipsum 1; dolor sit 1; amet 1;
Lorem ipsum 2; dolor sit 2; amet 2;
Lorem ipsum 3; dolor sit 3; amet 3;
```

I hope it helps you =)

Comment: I was trying right now, but it really seems impossible, a gonna change my structure 

Thanks for your help!